why converts Class attribute to instance attribute in python
why converts Class attribute to instance attribute in python?
class BaseClass:
    num_base_calls = 0
    def call_me(self):
        print('calling method on BaseClass!')
        self.num_base_calls += 1

obj1 = BaseClass()
obj2 = BaseClass()

obj1.call_me()
obj1.call_me()

obj2.call_me()
obj2.call_me()
obj2.call_me()

print(BaseClass.num_base_calls)
print(obj1.num_base_calls)
print(obj2.num_base_calls)

output >>
0
2
3


self.num_base_calls += 1 is basically self.num_base_calls = self.num_base_calls + 1. It first falls back to reading from the class attribute, but ends up setting self.num_base_calls. If you want to increment a class attribute, you need to explicitly increment it on the class object, not self.
